# Condition on the values of jsonb

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, jsonb

In my translations table I have **jsonb: values** where we can found per example: **{"en" =>"City"}** 
I'm trying to get all the un-translated translations ,
I've tried:

```
Translation.where(values.values="")
```

and something like

```
Translation.all.values.each do |language, translation|
  if translation.empty?
    #here I don't know how to should I do to get all the un-translated 
    #translations without overwriting
end
```

How can I do it properly?

Answer (score 0):

For empty json table field, like Translation.values = {}

```
Translation.where(values = '{}'")
```

For empty key in json table field, like Translation.values = { "mykey": "" }

```
Translation..where("(values-> 'mykey') IS NULL")
```

PostgreSQL json operators : https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.5/static/functions-json.html

Comment: and for an empty value of whatsoever key?

Comment: If you dont know the key ?

Comment: the keys are actually languages it's like so:  {"fr"=>"Bonjour", "de"=>"", "en"=>"Hello", "bg"=>"", "hr"=>"", "es"=>"", "hu"=>"", "it"=>"", "lt"=>"", "lv"=>"", "nl"=>"", "pl"=>"", "pt"=>"", "ro"=>"", "cs"=>""} 
And I want to get the translation only if it's not translated which in my case means blank ""